# How to integrate whole bootstrap template with angular js

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I have a bootstrap template and I am converting it into angular js.

But the problem I face is some navigation tools are not working and bootstrap template drop some functionality to work like scroll bar, sidebar navigation and similar functionality which require js to include. Is it a conflict ? Is it require to redevelop the whole template with angular js or I am missing anything to include with bootstrap before I converting.

I already read the documentation at https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap. but it is not helpful to convert whole template.

I just want some guidance how can I convert  a bootstrap template into angularjs.

I have not posted any code. Because Its very messy. And I wanted just a guidance about how it is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks David for editing.

Comment: yeah I saw, I removed my answer lol. Well, I am not sure what you mean by convert bootstrap to angular. angular bootstrap is a good solution. Use the custom build link at the top and select the components you want

Comment: My bootstrap template is developed using different javascript files and css. No angular js is used in it. Should I purchase new template with angular support or developed with angular + bootstrap or I can go with it. ?

Comment: ah ok, so you have a bootstrap template and you want to add angular?

Comment: Yes exactly. I have my bootstrap template. But it is not support angualr js.

Comment: I don't see an issue adding angular to this already existing bootstrap template, even with the JS files. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Okay. First of all, all the sidebar are not working. Than scroll bar is not displaying.